# Nuxt is reloading page after router push

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm sending ajax request on an order page for creating an order, after this I'm forming a link for redirect to "Thank you page" and using `$router.push`. But after this my page is fully reloading, and for me it's critical, coz on server side I've bunch of requests (so it's kinda long) and I'm losing my store. My order confirmation page has validate and asyncData methods, but I don't see anything that can force reloading page.

I tried:

1. Use `$router.replace` instead of `$router.push`
2. Use not a string, but an object with path `$router.push({ path: '...' })`
3. Use not a string, but an object with name and params `$router.push({ name: '...', params: {...} })`

I tried to do a sandbox, but I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: I assume you are not using `this.$forceUpdate();` or anything that could reload your page in any other way? Can you reproduce it locally? Maybe you point to http and your htaccess forces https? What if you redirect to another (test)-route? 
Anyway, I think it would be a nice user experience if your store (especially in the context of a webshop or similar) remains even after reload. So you could consider using: https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist#readme to keep the store in a cooke or session storage. That would maybe not resolve your reloading but the loss of your store...

Comment: 1. Yeah, I don't use $forceUpdate, but I'm cleaning get parameters after redirect. But I checked that, I commented that and reloading stayed. 2. I can reproduce it locally, I tried to comment everything, change it somehow, but behavior was the same. 3. I'm forming a link without http protocol, just '/order/confirmation/23?sendSuccess=true' 4. I didn't check other redirections actually, but nuxt-link is working okay 5

Comment: 5. And I can't persist my state, a lot of logic is attached to fact that my state is only for session + problem is more in nuxtServerInit coz it's not very fast

Comment: Well then I have no clue... But I would nontheless think about using persisting the state, even if it is just for one session. (-> sessionStorage)